# keep form value after submit it

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I know there are lots others question like this and i found 1.000 answer on the web but none of those work with my code :(
So can someone help me with how to keep email value after submit?

```
        <form name="login-registration" onSubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" action="" >
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="emailinput" id="emailinput" value ="" />
            <p id="emptyEmail" class="hidden">Email field is required</p>
            <p id="invalidEmail" class="hidden">Email you insert is invalid!</p>
            <label>Your password</label>
            <input type="password" name="pswinput" id="pswinput" value=""/>
            <p id="pswMinMax" class="hidden">Password should be from 4 to 8 caracters</p>
            <p id="pswLettNum" class="hidden">Password should be letters and numbers. No special caracters are allow</p>
            <label>Repeat password</label>
            <input type="password" name="pswrepeatinput" id="pswrepeatinput" value="" onblur="isValidPswRep()"/>
            <p id="pswR" class="hidden">Your passwords is different</p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="policy" name="policy" value="policy" /> <label>I agree</label>
            <p id="checkN" class="hidden">You must agree to our term</p>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />

        </form>
```

I try to put some code like:

```
<input type="email" name="emailinput" id="emailinput" value = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['lastname']); ?>" />
```

But that php line is just displayed inside the field input.

Comment: I hope you are giving .php extension to your file!

Comment: you are using post method in form

Comment: Check the file extension. Is it `.html` OR `.php`?

Comment: Your need to install PHP and/or configure your web server to give .php files to php interpreter. If not, it simply displays the contents of php tag.

Answer (score 1):

try using `$_POST['lastname']` instead of `$_GET['lastname']`

Answer (score 1):

1)If i am not wrong,i don't see any field with name="lastname" in your code above.

2)Use $_POST because you are posting your form data with method="post".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your file have `.php` as extension and php is installed on your server i would like you to notice that you have an error because you used a `POST` form while when you apply `value` to your input field  you are trying to use `$_GET` Further more you did not assign `lastname`to any input field, so use `emailinput` as you apply to this field `name="emailinput"`. You should change `htmlspecialchars($_GET['emailinput']);` to be `htmlspecialchars($_POST['emailinput']);`

So your code would look like this

```
<input type="email" name="emailinput" id="emailinput" value = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['emailinput']); ?>" />
```

This should print your variable inside your input field

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 problems there.

1. The fact that the php is displayed inline suggests that either you have wrong file extension (like the comments suggested), either file is not included in your "know how to read by php" (for lack of a better way to say it, my English is not perfect) directory.
2. You echo a get when you sent a post (as other answer suggested)

Also... WHY DOES YOUR QUESTION HAVE JS TAG (sorry for caps, wanted to be sure it sticks out)?

Comment: Glip! Sorry is because all my work is in Javascript and i thought was relevant but actually any code needed for this problem matter with Js. You are right!

Comment: Btw there is any way to save this value using Javascript or Ajax maybe?

Comment: You can submit through ajax. So you don't repopulate your values, you already have them there. I'll add a script after work (in like 7 hours) if I don't forget.

Comment: WoW! that would be great, thanks! Otherwise I will just look for it on google. Thanks for the help!