# Keep Form Value After submitting another form | Ruby on Rails | GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rest, http, post

On my Rails website, I have a webpage with many forms (for searching) with `GET`. The goods of `GET`, compared to `POST` is that the parameter is stored in the URL so that user can share URL with all the settings they made in the searching.

However, when the webpages get complex and there are multiple forms, say form A and form B. After I submit form A, the thing in form B will be gone, and the URL does not longer show anything about the content in form B (it only shows content in form A if I submit form A, vice versa).

So in [keep form value after submit it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960916/keep-form-value-after-submit-it), there's a suggestion of using `POST` instead of `GET`.. But it will make the URL not showing anything, which is bad for my use case.

Any idea about how I can solve it? The goal is to keep previous form result (if not changed) and also make the forms show in the URL (update when changed)

Code:

---

`result.html.erb`

```
<%= form_tag ('/foo/search'), :method => :get, :class => "form-inline" do %>
    <input name="search" type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="search name"/>
    <button type="submit"> search But</button>
<% end %>

....

<%= render :partial => 'page1' , ... %>
```

---

`_page1.html.erb`

```
....
<%= form_tag('/foo/search', method: "get", id: "myForm") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag "query[name]", params["query"].nil? ? nil : params["query"]["name"], placeholder: "name"%> 
<% end %>
....
```

When I submit the form in `result`, I can see `/foo/search?search=someThing` in URL; but after I submit `myForm` in the page, the `search=someThing` is just gone, but `/foo/search?query[name]=someOtherThing` is showing. How could I make it show `/foo/search?search=someThing&query[name]=someOtherThing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options here:

1. Make a **single** form. As long as your request hits the same `/foo/search` path, this seems like a naive general solution. I'm not sure what is the purpose of that `id` and `class` attributes of your forms, but you probably might restructure your styling and `js` code to work with a single form aswell.
2. Do not send your forms on `submit` event directly. Instead, catch it using `js`, generate the `URL` containing all the data from both the forms, and then hit it by hands.

   ```
   # coffee script & jquery example
   $('body').on 'submit', 'form', (event) =>
     # some logics to collect all the form data...
     value1 = $('body form input_field').val()
     # head to path with all that parameters injected
     window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com?search=someThing&query[name]=someOtherThing";
   ```

Comment: solved - expand the filter area to make it single form.

Comment: just got into another trouble... I may want to use the `  window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com?search=someThing&query[name]=someOtherThing";` thing but I find it hard to insert RESTful tag in between `stackoverflow.com?` and other query comes later.

Comment: @SeanLao well that should be as simple as iterating over an array (or hash?) containing all the form fields values and appending those key-values pairs to your domain name (`stackoverflow.com?` in this case), putting `&` sign between them.